# ckeditor updateElement() Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have applied CKeditor to a text area on my form, but  after Serializing the form, I checked it doesn't get the data from that field (description)
I found this in CKEditor's documentation:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.description.updateElement();
alert(document.getElementById( 'description' ).value);
```

I need to send that data somewhere through an API but it doesn't work without alert().
I wanted to grab this data into an variable like

```
var a = document.getElementById( 'description' ).value;
```

but it only works using the alert():

```
var a = alert(document.getElementById( 'description' ).value);
```

But I don't want that alert(). I just don't want to show its odd looking HTML code to the user.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the original textarea value to the ckeditor's value before serializing:

```
$("#OriginalTextAreaId").val(CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?here's my code
 <textarea id="description" name="description" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
  <script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );</script>